# Error: this template attempted to load component assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-winrt

I'm learning C++ with this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--setting-up-the-games-infrastructure. I have installed C++/WinRT templates and visualizer for VS2019 but when I want to create new Core App it says this message:

`Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates`.

I haven't found anythin useful in documentation on Customizing Project Templates. I installed UWP Essentials and NuGetRecommender [Preview] but it still isn't working.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 2):

For VS 2017 or later, to do C++ UWP development you need to install:

1. The *Universal Windows Platform* workload ( `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal`)
2. You need to add the *C++ Universal Windows Platform tools* optional component (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC`). Without this, the UWP workload only supports JavaScript+HTML and C# UWP development.
3. If you want to build ARM64 configurations for UWP, you'll also need to add the Individual Component *C++ Universal Windows Platform tools for ARM64* (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.VC.ARM64`). The package above otherwise covers x86, x64, and ARM.

> `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards` is installed as part of the UWP Workload.

> *UWP Essentials* is just some individual's extension on Visual Studio Marketplace. It's not a Microsoft package. It also appears to just bundle up some other extensions.

See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-lightweight-visual-studio-15-installer/) for an overview of the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but how I can install it?

Comment: Run the Visual Studio Installer application on your system. Select your install. Click Modify.